# Flink with Guava cache - The implementation of the ProcessFunction is not serializable

Tags: scala, serialization, guava, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I implemented a ProcessFunction that uses a Guava cache to filter a stream of incoming events. The code looks like this :

```
object myJob {
 private def updateCache(cacheObject, someValue) = {}
 private def getCacheValue(cacheObject, someKey) = {}

 override def run(params, executionEnv) = {
  val inputStream = executionEnv.stream

  val c = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()

  val outStream = inputStream.process(new ProcessFunction() { 
    updateCache()
    getCacheValue} 
    )
 }
}
```

On submitting the job to Flink, I'm getting the following error :

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the ProcessFunction is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:99)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.clean(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1560)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.clean(DataStream.java:185)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.process(DataStream.java:666)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream.process(DataStream.scala:686)
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? How can I resolve this serialization error?

Comment: I resolved this issue by moving the cache object declaration, outside the run function. Made it a private value.

Answer (score 0):

The error says basically that you are depending on an Object that is not serializable for Flink. In the case that You have shown, marking the field with the loader as lazy should fix the issue:

```
   lazy val c = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
```

Generally, in such case, You should refer to the Flink's [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/types_serialization.html), which explains the issue